# ошибка в работе кода swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, swift3

только недавно начал работать в Свифт и еще очень много не понимаю поэтому такой вопрос

Я написал вот такой код

```
if let myData = data{
                do{
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let data = myJson["data"] as AnyObject? {

                        let id = data["id"] as! NSString?
                            print (id!)
                        let logo = data["logo"] as! NSString?
                            print (logo!)
                        let name = data["name"] as! NSString?
                            print (name!)
                    }
                    let status = myJson["status"] as! String!
                        print (status!)

                    if(status == "OK")
                    {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();

                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
                    }
                }
```

при правильном ввидении логина и пароля все хорошо мой JSON код приходит и я могу его распарсить но если логин или пароль неверный то программу выбивает и выдает ошибку fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

проверку логина и пароля произвожу на сервере

Comment: Возможно Вы пытаетесь достать ключ, которого нет. Когда приходит ошибка, как выглядит JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что падает на каком-то из `!`. Либо перепишите, дабы исключить вероятность, что там где делаете force unwrap проскакочит nil, либо воспользуйтесь [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). С ее помощью можно просто и безопасно распарсить JSON.

Answer (score 0):

вместо этого кода

```
let id = data["id"] as! NSString?
                        print (id!)
                    let logo = data["logo"] as! NSString?
                        print (logo!)
                    let name = data["name"] as! NSString?
                        print (name!)
                }
                let status = myJson["status"] as! String!
                    print (status!)
```

попробуйте сделать следующее

```
if let id = data["id"] as? String {
  print (id)
}

if let logo = data["logo"] as String {
  print (logo)
}

if let name = data["name"] as? String {
   print (name)
}
```

В таком случае вы зайдете в тело условия только в том случае, если у вас под этими ключами есть значение и у этого значения тип данных `String`

Comment: так пробовал всеравно крашит по идеи нужно дописать какой нибудь else myJson == nil {return} но почему то не работает